# Java Pattern replacement in C++ (library)

Tags: java, c++, boost

I am porting Java code in C++ where Java code has been using Pattern class to parse regular expression.  Anyone know any library or open source in C++ for regular expressions as replacement for Java?
I am looking on Linux.

Thanks

Comment: How about boost::regex or std::regex?

Comment: i have to check it and compare with java . Thanks

Comment: @ForEveR: Would using the entire Boost library be an overkill for just one usage or can the Boost library be *broken down* into given pieces?

Comment: I would recommend using the new C++11 [standard regex library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) as well, but note that not all compilers fully support it yet. VS2010 seems to have good support, while GCC's support is lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard library has [regex functionality](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/regex/) included. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries are generally regarded as of very high quality. [Boost.regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) library deals with regular expressions. You can use just that one, and don't have to include all separate Boost libraries.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. i got a comparison chart http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines. Its seems boost.regex would be good replacement.